# :find multiple file names

Tags: find

I apologise if this was asked before, but I couldn't find anything similar.

I am trying to write a simple command to jump to a test file, using the current file name. I have managed to achieve this using:

```
command Spec :find %:r.spec.js
```

If my current buffer name is `foo.js` this will try to jump to `foo.spec.js`.

The problem is some projects use the `*.test.js` extension therefore I would like to be able to look for both and to jump to either available. Something like:

```
command Spec :find %:r.(spec|test).js
```

However, this does not work. I have tried escaping the atom but vim then just treats it as a literal. Is there any way to achieve this **without any plugin**? I should mention that using bash commands are also not an option since I use Windows quite a lot as well.

Ideally, if multiple files are found, I would get a wildmenu, but I'd be happy with opening the first found too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vim globs (like those used in find), alternation between two words can be done using the `{a,b}` syntax.  This will work interactively, presenting a wildmenu, if you press tab.

```
:find %:r.{spec,test}.js<TAB>
```

Unfortunately, it won't work from a "Spec" command wrapper, since `:find` does not tolerate multiple matches.  Here is one solution using `glob()` and `inputlist()`.  Typing `:Spec` will present a choice if there are multiple matches.

```
 function! Spec(bang)
    let files = glob('%:r.{spec,test}.js', 1, 1)
    if empty(files)
        echohl Error | echo 'nothing found' | echohl None
        return
    endif
    if len(files) == 1
        execute 'edit' . a:bang files[0]
        return
    endif

    let choice = inputlist(map(copy(files), 'v:key+1 . ": " . v:val'))
    if choice > 0
        execute 'edit' . a:bang files[choice-1]
    endif
endfunction

command! -bang Spec :call Spec('<bang>')
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me... I don't think `:find` uses this kind of regex. It seems to accept basic wildcards (e.g. `?` or `[...]`) but it complains if that expands to more than one filename...

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work for me in gVim Windows `E345: Cannot find file "foo.(spec|test).js in path` :( It looks like escaping the special characters treats them as part of the string literal

Comment: @filbranden, there is some weirdness I can't explain, check out `:echo glob(expand('%:r') . '*\(spec\|test\).js')` vs `:echo glob(expand('%:r') . '\(spec\|test\).js')`.

@AndreiNemes fundamentally the problem is :find won't handle multiple filenames.  If you type `:find %:r.\(spec\|test\).js<tab>` it will work as expected, but not as part of :Spec command

Comment: This works! I had to change the glob to `let files = glob('./**/*' . expand('%:r') . '.{spec.js,test.js}', 1, 1)` though. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: By the way, you forgot to `return` on the `len === 1` case :)

Comment: I release the above code into the public domain. @AndreiNemes

Comment: Great, thanks @Mass. If anyone is interested in this functionality, I have made the code available [here](https://github.com/simplysh/toggle-spec.vim).

Answer (score 1):

One possible simple approach is to use a [`:try`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Atry) block to catch an error while trying the `*.spec.js` filename and then fallback to the `*.test.js` filename if that fails.

Perhaps something as simple as:

```
command! Spec try | find %:t:r.spec.js | catch /^Vim(find):E345:/ | find %:t:r.test.js | endtry
```

(Note I used `%:t:r` to use just the basename of the file, so that `:find` gets a filename only and will use `'path'` to locate it. That's not the case if the original file was in a subdirectory and you used `%:r`, in which case it would only look for the `*.spec.js` file in the same directory as the original file.)

One small issue with this solution is that, when neither file exists, it will only complain about the latter `*.test.js`, which might give the user the wrong impression that that's the preferred filename...

You can fix that by using a second `:try` block and issuing a more appropriate error message in that case.

The command gets longer already, so I'll start breaking lines for clarity:

```
command! Spec
  \   try
  \ |   find %:t:r.spec.js
  \ | catch /^Vim(find):E345:/
  \ |   try
  \ |     find %:t:r.test.js
  \ |   catch /^Vim(find):E345:/
  \ |     echoerr "E345: Can't find file \"".expand("%:t:r").".spec.js\" or \"".expand("%:t:r").".test.js\" in path"
  \ |   endtry
  \ | endtry
```

At this point it already makes sense to break this out into a function, and have the `Spec` command call the function...

If you use a function, you might want to consider using [`findfile()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#findfile%28%29) to locate an existing file, possibly use a list and a loop to handle possible extensions in a more flexible way, perhaps consider creating or offering to create the file if it doesn't exist...

But then, you're already halfway through writing your own plug-in for this feature, so you might consider adopting one. The [vim-projectionist](https://github.com/tpope/vim-projectionist) plug-in by Tim Pope is a great plug-in for jumping between related files in a project and it's quite flexible so you can configure it to match the paths in your project.

Comment: Branching by exception looks itchy.

Comment: I went with the other suggestion, thanks for your input!

Comment: @AndreiNemes Glad you found a workable solution!